# Getting flask content block to only show selected number of items

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing my first flask application and I have a block that looks like this:

```
{%- block content %}
<ol> 
{%- for item in items | sort(reverse=True, attribute=date) %}
    {%- if item in items[:3] %}
        <li>

            blah blah

        </li>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
</ol>
{%- endblock content %}
```

I'd like to only show the first three items sorted by date. Currently, I can only get all the items to show by removing the `items[:3]`, not the 3 newest. How can I get only three items to display? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use flask's built in loop context variable:

```
{%- for item in items | sort(reverse=True, attribute=date) %}
    {%- if loop.index <= 3 %}
        <li>
            blah blah
        </li>
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

for more information:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for